# How to deal with a file getting added to a wrong commit in git?

Tags: git

I have a past commit in my git history where I was working on a feature 'X' and committed a file accidentally which had nothing to do with this feature along with the other relevant files.

Now I am working on the feature 'Y' which is actually related to the file which got committed earlier by mistake.

How to deal with this scenario in the best way?

Comment: how is your repo structured? that is, how is feature X merged back into you 'master', and where does feature Y branch off? Finally, what are the 'problems' hidden in that file (if any). You may just be able to continue without having to 'unfix' anything, just add a note onto the next Y commit.

Comment: I have to branches 'master' and 'version X'. I am working on version X branch and all I have is a series of commits.

Comment: Don't monkey with published history. Just supplement your commit with git-notes, and move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how I would have dealt with your problem:

Start an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i COMMIT-OF-FEAT-X^ # notice the ^ at the end
```

Then change *pick* to *edit* for the concerned commit.
You would then be *in* (please suggest a better wording) that specific commit.

Remove the file from the commit:

```
git remove --cached wrong_file
```

That file would then be untracked.

Continue the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

You're done.

You can now just switch to the *feat-Y* branch and add the file, commit it, or do whatever you want with it:

```
git co feat-Y
git add wrong_file
```